# How did jiujitsu spread to Britain?

Tags: history, jujutsu

['Suffrajitsu': How the suffragettes fought back using martial arts](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-34425615) talks about jiujitsu being used by suffragettes in pre-WWI Britain.

How did the martial art spread from Japan to Britain?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edith_Margaret_Garrud

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, it was introduced to the UK by [Edward William Barton-Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_William_Barton-Wright) in 1898.